# Attempt to implement discussion subjects with tree structure.

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, javafx-8

(language java, difficulty/time consuming: pretty high)

im up for exam in 10 days. And im bringing a chat program along to the exam, just to 
have a program with the entire curriculum implemented in it.

What im trying to do is to structure the different discussion subjects in a tree structure so that
discussions can branch from one subject into  seperate sub-subjects which would then result in the first subject to have children(obviously not a binary tree, since you can have endless sub-subjects within one
subject).

What im having difficulty with right now is to add these subjects to the tree,
The  tree node im going to add would then contain a collection containing of all the subjects it 
wants to address,  if we have a subject path going like this  girls --> arms --> finger 
allready in the tree.
then some1 writes a message with the  subjects girls,arms  (path: girls --> arms), then i need an algorithm, basically breadth first that searches the entire top level for a match of
the 'girls' subject,  if there is a mis-match  then we should create subject girls at this level of the tree and give it arms as a child.  If we did find a match, we have to search all of the children for a   'arms' node etc.

i could show some code, but i think it's more of the theory nature of it.

to describe it further im trying to add this tree to a TreeTableView in javaFx 8. 
and the basic problem is to find a algorithm that searches a path, is able to stop when it finds a match and insert a node.  when i find the level in the tree that corresponds to my search, im just going to add it within the nodes children, which is a list, so that part of it is super easy.

any help would be greatly apreciated, im really bummed out about this stopping my work this badly :)

thanks ! - and sorry for the no-code examples, it just seemed to cluster this question.

Comment: Your question seems to describe pretty well what you need to do.  Which part is giving you problems?

Comment: `for(Node node: Nodes) if(node.name = thisName) { thisNode = node; break; }`. Is this what you are having trouble implementing? If so, perhaps, you picked a problem that is just too complex for your current level. Try binary search, perhaps, or check if a string is a palindrome. If this is not it, then I just don't understand what you are talking about at all. Post some code (don't worry about "cluttering the question"), and annotate it with some information about parts that you cannot get working.